# Preg_match 0-9 validation - Don't accept zero(0)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Im working on validation for phone number and ext number, What I need to do is that if there is no extension number available,  I should put just a zero(0). My problem is the fields don't accept the digit "0".

How can I fix it?

This is the expression I used.

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $ext)
```

code

```
<?php

$Errext="";
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if (empty($_POST["ext"])) {
            $Errext = "Please enter your extension #. If you do not have an extension # then enter zero(0).";
        } else {
            $ext = test_input($_POST["ext"]);
            if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $ext)) {
                $Errext = "Only Numbers is allowed";
            } else {
                $extSuc = 1;
            }
        }  
}

function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }


?>
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="" id="form1">
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ext">Ext</label> 
                                <input class="form-control" name="ext" type="number" id="ext" value="<?php echo $ext; ?>"/>
                                <span>
                                    <?php echo $Errext; ?>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

    <button name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">Submit</button>
</form>
```

you can run the code here

http://phpfiddle.org/

Thanks.

**I just solve the problem.**

```
if ($_POST["ext"]=='') {
```

Sorry for the big trouble and thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to match here?

Comment: numbers from 0-9 sir

Comment: the expression I used dont accept zero..just the zero

Comment: I just add a code sir

Answer (score 1):

You never enter your regex. `0` is [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

```
if (empty($_POST["ext"])) {
```

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, **non-zero** value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

Try `if (isset($_POST["ext"])) {`. You also then could use

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php to verify the string is numeric... or you could update the regex to require a number be present. The `*` allows for the string to be empty, make it a `+` and a value must be present.

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST["ext"])` what is it? Also output `$Errext`, what is it?

Comment: @misdirection a fitting username I see.

Answer (score 0):

This does not accept a zero:

```
preg_match("/^[1-9]*$/", $ext)
```

Comment: sorry sir if my problem is not clear.. the expression i used didnt accept my input if I just put zero.

Answer (score 0):

That's you want...

```
var_dump(preg_match("/^[1-9]*$/", '0987777777')); // return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you need remove that 0 and replace it with minimum of your range.
`preg_match("/^[1-9]*$/", '0987777777')`